# Algorithm evaluating user-defined functions

Tags: algorithm

Hello I have some homework that consists of extending a lisp interpreter. We are to build three primitives with pre-evaluated arguments ( for exemple <= ), and three primitives who do their own evaluation ( for example if ).
I went beyond the call of duty and created the only fun function in the bounds of this exercice : (defun) [it's the common lisp keyword for defining a user-function].

I would like to know if my algorithm for managing a user-defined function call is worthwhile.

In pseudo code, here it goes :

```
get list of parameters # (x y z)
get list of arguments  # (1 2 3)
get body of function   # (+ x (* y z))
for each parameter, arg     # x
  body = replace(parameter, argument, body) # (+ 1 (* y z))
                                            # (+ 1 (* 2 z))
                                            # (+ 1 (* 2 3))
eval(body)                                  # 7
```

Are there better ways to accomplish this?
Thanks.

EDIT: replace() is a function recursing on sub-lists of body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found better, no one proposed better, the question generated no interest whatever, and I'm on a rampage to close my opened questions, so here is the answer :

my algorithm was good enough.